# Python Numpy find row index of array consisting of 5 values, by searching for 2 values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi apologies if the title is confusing, I am new to numpy and not used to the terminology.

Suppose we have a numpy array acting as a world map. 
The parameters are (x y r g b) - all are int16

Example:

```
a = np.array([[  0,   0,   0, 255,   0], #index 0
              [  0,   1,   0,   0, 255], #index 1
              [  0,   2,   0, 255,   0]]) #index 2
```

Now we want to find the index value of the row with x and y values (0, 2) - hence the row with index 2.

```
[  0,   1,   0,   0, 255] #index 2
```

How would I do this without also inputting the rest of the values (r g b)? Basically we are searching a five value row with two values - how would I do this?

Comment: Can you show the code you have already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your data:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[  0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
              [  0,   1,   0,   0, 255],
              [  0,   2,   0, 255,   0]])

a,b = 0,2 # [a,b] is what we are looking for, in the first two cols
```

**Here's the solution to get the row index containing [a,b]:**

```
found_index = np.argmax(np.logical_and(arr[:,0]==[a],arr[:,1]==[b]))
print (found_index)
```

**Output:**

> 2

**Explanation:**

The best way to understand how this works, is by printing each part of it:

```
print (arr[:,0]==[a])
```

Outputs:

> [ True  True  True]

```
print (arr[:,1]==[b])
```

Outputs:

> [False False  True]

```
print (np.logical_and(arr[:,0]==[a],arr[:,1]==[b]))
# print (np.logical_and([ True  True  True], [False False  True]))
```

Outputs:

[False False  True]

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the rows up to the second column, and check if they are equal to `[0,2]`. Then use [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) setting `axis` to `1` to set to `True` those that satisfy all conditions, and use the boolean array to index the `ndarray`:

```
a = np.array([[  0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
              [  0,   1,   0,   0, 255],
              [  0,   2,   0, 255,   0]])

a[(a[:,:2] == [0,2]).all(1)]
# array([[  0,   2,   0, 255,   0]])
```

Comment: originalRow = a[(a[:, :2] == [x, y]).all(1)]
        originalIndex = numpy.where(numpy.all(originalRow==a, axis=1))[0][0]                                   for anyone wondering how to quickly get the index of this row.